# htaccess redirect 301 all to one domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 3 domains:

domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com

I want to 301 redirect all to domain3.com/$1. That includes domains with www and non-www.

domain1.com -> domain3.com
www.domain1.com/$1 -> domain3.com/$1

domain2.com -> domain3.com
www.domain2.com/$1 -> domain3.com/$1

domain3.com X-> domain3.com (no redirect)
www.domain3.com/$1 -> domain3.com/$1

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following will 301 redirect domain1.com and domain2.com to domain3.com. Add the www if you want it for domain3.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the above was not working for me, but when i changed it slightly to this, it started to work fine.

        RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]